Как на javascript сделать плавный переход по hash в url?
Динамика такая вводим hash в url и плавно перемещаемся к одноимённому элементу с id на странице.
Примеры: как тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript#средний_уровень или тут https://doka.guide/js/window-history/#kak-ponyat.

scroll-behavior: smooth;
